# android get selected string in main activity

Tags: android

This is nested class that implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener. This provides a callback method that  notify my application when an item has been selected from the Spinner. But I do not know how to pass Selected String value to main activity?

```
public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
    String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // Do nothing.
  }

}
```

I call in main activity like that

```
     public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
     // I need the selected value here.........
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your listener is a nested child class of the relevant Activity, you should be able to simply call a method from the Activity directly?

```
public void doSomething(String selected) {
    // do something here...
} 

public class YourItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        doSomething(selected); // <=== THIS
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the post, please check it out, this explains what I want

Comment: Could you please help me to do that ?

Comment: At the location you've indicated, there is no way to access the value - it is not available yet. At that spot, you are simply binding an event listener. The value will be available inside the event listener and then it is your responsibility to pass it back to some relevant code in the parent activity - you can do this by calling a method. Or, perhaps you add a getter property on your CustomOnItemSelectedListener class.

Comment: Can you help me for this method ?

Comment: How can I get the selected value from the spinner ?

Answer (score 0):

In your custom SpinnerAdapter you can set the string as a Tag on the View

```
 myFirstView.setTag("First");
```

and in onItemSelected callback you can get the Tag from the View.

```
 String selectedContent = (String)view.getTag();
```

Comment: Could you please help me to do that ?